# Adding a line break inside a string under certain circumstances

Tags: c#, html, line-breaks, sitefinity

I have an old Sitefinity site that I am working on, and on certain products pages there are a selection of cut glass options available. These are listed as thumbnail images that can be clicked and opened into a popup window. Right now, the code is set up to create the divs containing the thumbnail section and the thumbnails themselves, and they are displayed one right after the other as a continuous string. The thumbnails drop down to the next line when they reach the width of the area they are in. The problem right now is that there are three cut class thumbnails that need to be grouped together, even if that means moving them to the next line.

I'm not sure how to proceed, as I don't want to have to do more work than necessary. Also, this is not code I created--it is someone else's that I must edit (the person is not available to answer questions).

Here is the bit of code that sets up the divs containing the thumbnails (GlassItem is the name of the div that encloses each cut glass thumbnail image):

```
protected String BuildCutGlass(Guid CurrentPage)
    {
        StringBuilder Glass = new StringBuilder();

        using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sitefinity"].ToString()))
        {
            cn.Open();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id, BrandID, GlassName, Thumbnail, LargeImage, Ordinal, (SELECT Window_Brands.BrandName FROM Window_Brands WHERE Window_Brands.BrandPage = BrandID) AS BrandName FROM Window_Brand_cutglass WHERE BrandID = ?PageID AND Thumbnail IS NOT NULL AND LargeImage IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Ordinal", cn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("PageID", CurrentPage.ToString()));

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader["Thumbnail"].ToString().Length > 1 && reader["LargeImage"].ToString().Length > 1)
                        Glass.Append(String.Format("<div class='GlassItem'><a href='{0}' class='CutGlassPopup Icon'><img src='{1}' alt='{2}' width='77' height='77' /></a><a href='{0}' class='CutGlassPopup'>{2}</a></div>", Revere.GetImagePath(reader["LargeImage"].ToString()), Revere.GetImagePath(reader["Thumbnail"].ToString()), reader["GlassName"].ToString()));
                }
            }

            cn.Close();
        }

        return Glass.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a way to indicate which ones need to be kept together? I would suggest keeping a count variable and incrementing it inside the while loop and append a `</br>` or something to the string builder whenever you hit a specific number.. then reset the count... but really you need an additional group flag in the database to do this properly.

Comment: May be just put them all into one empty styleless div if the layout handles such divs correctly. If you can't determine which of them should be grouped then you should redesign you data storage with some additional flag or type field.

Comment: I think what I will do is edit the database and add a new field to represent the thumbnail id. Then I can do a sql select based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't the quick fix you are looking for, but the reason that this code is hard to work with is because your data retrieving code is mixed in with your html generating code. I'd create a class for `GlassItem` and modify the method to return a list of them.

```
public class GlassItem
{
    public string LargeImagePath {get;set;}
    public string ThumbnailPath {get;set;}
    public string GlassName {get;set;}
}

protected List<GlassItem> GetGlassItems(Guid CurrentPage)
{
    var items = new List<GlassItem>();

   using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sitefinity"].ToString()))
   {
       cn.Open();

       MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id, BrandID, GlassName, Thumbnail, LargeImage, Ordinal, (SELECT Window_Brands.BrandName FROM Window_Brands WHERE Window_Brands.BrandPage = BrandID) AS BrandName FROM Window_Brand_cutglass WHERE BrandID = ?PageID AND Thumbnail IS NOT NULL AND LargeImage IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Ordinal", cn);
       cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("PageID", CurrentPage.ToString()));

       using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
           while (reader.Read())
           {
               if (reader["Thumbnail"].ToString().Length > 1 && reader["LargeImage"].ToString().Length > 1)
                {
                    items.Add(new GlassItem 
                            { 
                                LargeImagePath = Revere.GetImagePath(reader["LargeImage"].ToString()), 
                                ThumbnailPath = Revere.GetImagePath(reader["Thumbnail"].ToString()), 
                                GlassName = reader["GlassName"].ToString()
                            });
                }   
           }
       }

       cn.Close();
   }

    return items;
}
```

Then you can use linq etc to figure out which items you want on each line, or you can use a simple loop as well.

```
    var items = GetGlassItems(new Guid("..."));
    StringBuilder Glass = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < items.Count();i++)
    {
        Glass.Append(String.Format("<div class='GlassItem'><a href='{0}' class='CutGlassPopup Icon'><img src='{1}' alt='{2}' width='77' height='77' /></a><a href='{0}' class='CutGlassPopup'>{2}</a></div>", 
                                    items[i].LargeImagePath, 
                                    items[i].Thumbnail, 
                                    items[i].GlassName));
        if(i % 5 == 0 )
        {   
            // new line every 5 items
            Glass.AppendLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a try tomorrow and see if it works. It seems like a good idea. I just hope the old Sitefinity code can handle it.

Comment: Ok, I gave your code a try and it mostly works. However, the if statement that is made to append a new line every 5 items does not work as expected. I had to make a change in that simply using Glass.AppendLine() did not do anything. Right now I have Glass.Append("<div style='clear:both;'></div>"). This works but, it adds a new line right after the first thumbnail. I have 7 thumbnails, and the code should be placing a new line every 5 thumbnails. What could be wrong with the code that is adding a new line incorrectly after the first thumbnail in the set?

Comment: All right, I solved the issue. The code works great now. Thanks a lot!